# S3 get_object..iter_lines() skipping lines with islice/zip

Tags: python, generator, boto3, python-itertools

```
response = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=file )

def generate_files(resp, N):
    while True:
        line = list(islice(resp["Body"].iter_lines(), 0, 10))
        if not line:
            break
        yield line
    return
```

However, when I call my generator, the result is not as expected.

```
for line in generate_files(response, 10):
    print('--')
    print([l.decode('utf-8') for l in line])
```

Instead of going from line 0 to 9, then 10 to 19, then 20 to 29 etc.. It skips ahead an arbitrary number of lines between generator calls. So it is returning lines 0 to 9. Then lines 17 to 26. Then lines 33 to 40 etc.. It's also moving forward. So it seems to be reading the stream even after islice's line call. I've also tried with zip and get the same result.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

I think that the problem is in iter_lines, because iter_lines is not reentrant safe. Calling this method multiple times causes some of the received data being lost. In case you need to call it from multiple places, you should in my opinion use the resulting iterator object instead, e.g.:

```
r = requests.get('https://httpbin.org/stream/20', stream=True)
lines = r.iter_lines()

for line in lines:
    print(line)
```

Sorry, but there is poorly off for the code, so I can't to check this.
More informations is in the url site: https://2.python-requests.org/projects/3/user/advanced/

Please, if you check it, give a feedback.